# Is there a prolog clpb coding which can solve this puzzle involving knights, knave, and spies?

Tags: prolog, clpb

There are three people (Alex, Brook and Cody), one of whom is a
knight, one a knave, and one a spy.The knight always tells the
truth, the knave always lies, and the spy can either lie or tell
the truth. 
Alex says: "Cody is a knave." 
Brook says: "Alex is a
knight." 
Cody says: "I am the spy." 
Who is the knight, who the knave, and who the spy? Solve this puzzle by prolog clpb

Comment: You need to add an attempted solution in your question to get a response. This will almost certainly require you to ask a more specific question than "do X using Y".

Comment: :- use_module(library(clpb)).

example_knights(1, [C]) :-
            ?- sat(A=:= ~C).
          
% Example 2: A says: "I am a knave, but B isn't."
% B says: " A is a knight."
example_knights(2, [A]) :-
       ?- sat(B=:= A ).
% Example 3: A says: "At least one of us is a knave."
%C says: "I am the spy."
example_knights(3, [C]) :-
       ?- sat(C=:=(C)).     I was trying to do the basic of it but it is too short for giving an answer. And using matrix 3by 3, I was struggling of how to write that code in prolog

Comment: can you please edit your *question* and add the code in a formatted manner. Also this code does not have a matrix, please be clear about what you intend the code to do but what is does instead.

Comment: Definitely look at [Knights and Knaves in Prolog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oEAa2pQKqQU)